# Hide pushed commit on one file

Tags: git, github

I pushed something that should not be seen (credentials) and re-pushed something to hide it.
What can I do to erase or previous file commit that nobody can see it in previous commits.
Thx

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32840254/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+remove+sensitive+files